# Chrome devtools extension: adding more filters to console

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Devtools console now allows only filtering by error, log, warning, etc a handful of filters.

Any way to add custom filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [`chrome.devtools` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) doesn't allow you to do anything with the Console panel from extensions.

This may be an interesting [feature request](https://crbug.com/new).

Also, there is an API in the expermental status limbo, [`chrome.experimental.devtools.console`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental_devtools_console), that would enable you to create a custom Console panel altogether. But, it's unlikely to become available anytime soon.

Meanwhile, if you want it for your own uses — note that with regex filtering you can create pretty powerful filters.